# Random word from text JavaScript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, random

I need to get 1 random word from text, but I don't now how to do it with Javascript.

Code:

```
function someFunction() {

    // something here

var word;

$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: link,
     success: function(data) {
        word = getWord(data); // get random word from data
     }
});

}



function getWord(text) {

// help me please)

}
```

I hope it's easy) Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Y9bCG/

```
alert(getWord("there is a book there"));
function getWord(data)
{   
    var splits=data.split(' ');    

    var randNumMax = splits.length-1;
    var randInt = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (randNumMax + 1)));
    return splits[randInt];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
function getWord(text) {
    var words = text.split(' ');
    return words[getRandomInt(0, words.length-1)];
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```